# HeaderHttpSessionStrategy x-auth-token is it safe?

Tags: spring-session

Is it safe to use HeaderHttpSessionStrategy? one can get hold of the x-auth-token and the same session can be simulated across browsers and machines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that cookies themselves are in fact HTTP headers. The header named `Cookie` contains your cookie, which makes your concern applicable to both session strategies Spring Session provides out of the box (although cookies can be considered *safer* since they are domain restricted).

Ultimately, what will make both strategies *safe* is the use of SSL transport, i.e. HTTPS.